# How to run your specific espresso test class/test cases using spoon?

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-espresso, ui-testing, spoon

I tried adding :

```
spoon {
     if (project.hasProperty('spoonClassName')) {
         className = project.spoonClassName  
        }
    }
```

But i am getting below mentioned error :
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'AndroidTestApp'.

> Could not find method spoon() for arguments [build_efbwwyd8gychv00diqry4hwki$_run_closure1$_closure3$_closure7@1c104303] on repository container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultRepositoryHandler.

Can anybody tell me how to exactly add above snippet and in which gradle file ?